# AVR program code location

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, atmega, avr-gcc, non-volatile-memory

I'm working with an ATmega328P and I wanted to interface with the flash memory writing data to it with the macros provided by [avr-libc](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__boot.html). This is the memory map for my chip:

[image: ATmega memory map]
<sub>(source: [avr-tutorials.com](http://www.avr-tutorials.com/sites/default/files/Memory%20Map%20Small.jpg))</sub>

I don't understand where the program code is exactly located when compiled. What I mean is: How can I be sure the address I use in boot_page_fill and boot_page_write is not used for the program code? Do I need to use the "–section-start" linker option to move the program code to a specific location and be sure the flash page I'm going to use doesn't overwrite that code?

NOTE: The data to write in the flash is unknown at compile time.

Comment: http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_reloc_code

Comment: As I said, I already read that! but my question still unclear. What's the relation between the flash pages location I'm gonna write on and the program code location?

Comment: Whatever you tell the linker. If you don't want them to collide then you need to make sure that they don't.

Comment: boot_page_xxxx functions are called by bootloader running in *boot flash section*. I.e. normally you are uploading binary image into *application flash section*. You don't need care about *sections* etc. You just need pass binary to bootloader, typically via serial/USB or read it from external flash disk (SPI). Or do you try to implement bootloader which can update itself?

Comment: "Normally" the program code is located at address 0. As already mentioned, you can tell the linker to use a different address. After reset, the controller executes code starting at address 0 by default. You can set fuses to tell the controller to execute code from the boot flash section first. The boot section code then has to make sure to jump to address 0 after it is done. In every case, you would have to know your code size and calculate where it is safe to write to the flash without overwriting the application code. Note that it is only possible to write flash from the boot flash section!

Comment: @Rev1.0 So if I want to reserve 3 pages of flash for writing an array in the future. Do I have to tell the linker to move the program code at address 0x180 (since e/page 128 bytes) ? Is it a good idea to locate the already-known number of pages on top of the flash and then tell the linker put the program code below?

Comment: I would place my user data right before the boot loader (the boot loader start address depends on the fuse settings) and leave the application at address 0. Note that you CAN NOT write any data to the flash from the "normal" application. You HAVE TO use a boot loader. I am not sure that this is what you have in mind.

Comment: @Rev1.0 Yes! thanks for the recommendation! What you said is not a problem because the avr-libc has macros that interface with flash memory doing all the "dirty work" for me.

Comment: Note that the avr-libc functions can NOT write flash memory when the code is executed from the application section as well.

Comment: take a look at this, very clearly explained: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment

Answer (score 2):

Unless you tune your linker, the program will always start at address 0 and grow up. Additionally, if you have a bootloader, it will start at one of predefined addresses (either 0xF80, 0xF00, 0E00 or 0xC00, see table 26-7 in datasheet), and usually go to the top of the memory.

When people use flash memory for data, they usually put it as high as they can. So:

(1) Determine the memory top -- this depends on bootloader that you have. If you have Optiboot, it usually takes 512 or 256 words: https://code.google.com/p/optiboot/wiki/HowOptibootWorks , so we will assume it starts at 0xE00.

(2) Determine how much data you need. Lets say you need 256 (0x100) bytes. This means you will place your datablock at 0xE00 - 0x100 = 0xD00. You can pass values between 0xD00 and 0xDFE to boot_page_* functions.

(3) Write your program.

(4) Check how much space it occupies. It can take up to (0xD00 - 1) = 3328 bytes. When I compile from command-line, I use 'avr-size' for that:

```
$ avr-size -C --mcu=atmega328 firmware.elf
AVR Memory Usage
----------------
Device: atmega328

Program:     904 bytes (2.8% Full)
(.text + .data + .bootloader)

Data:          2 bytes (0.1% Full)
(.data + .bss + .noinit)
```

Look at 'program' section -- only 904 bytes are used, plenty of space left. If you see a number of 3328 or more there, make your program shorter. Otherwise, the program will compile and upload, but it will crash randomly.